# How difficult it is to reverse engeneer code from UWP / Windows Store apps?

Tags: windows-store-apps, uwp, reverse-engineering, disassembly

I know that apps submitted to Windows Store are compiled using .NET Native. How difficult it is to reverse engineer the source codes from apps downloaded from windows store? Does it make sense to obfuscate the code first?

Comment: There's a discussion about this here: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/08/20/net-native-what-it-means-for-universal-windows-platform-uwp-developers/ (search the page for "reverse engineering") and there's also a similar (closed) question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129802/does-uwps-net-native-together-with-asynchronous-programming-make-obfuscation-i

Answer (score 2):

Even if it gets compiled in native, the behaviour of the program can be read using a native debugger, like http://x64dbg.com/ (in assembler, of course...). The exact original code can't be read.

So in the end it depends on the complexity of your program and the patience/interest of the person doing the reverse engeneering.

Answer (score 0):

if you compile it in native it is not possible to reverse engineer it.
if you compile it in managed, they are open, any decent dev can go to see your code.

hth
-g

Comment: Hi, please check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31981569/how-to-configure-net-native-in-visual-studio-2015) to understand how to compile a UWP app with the .Net native toolchain. Based on that you will be able to compile natively or not. This refers to VS2015 UWP app developed with a managed language. hth -g